# How can I TransformRequest GET parameters with Angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, http-get, query-string, ngresource

When using ngResource/$resource, it is possible to implement custom (de)serialisation by specifying transformRequest/transformResponse. However these only control the request's body (data), so how can one manipulate the query parameters in a GET request?

Specifically, I would like to json-encode all the parameter values.

Simple case:
?user=123 is user with id 123
?user="123" is user with name 123

Complex case:
Passing objects/hashes in a GET request. For example using a mongo-like syntax to specify request criteria/projection. (Please note this question is not about mongo specifcally)

Comment: $resource takes an actions.params option which can be a hash of functions against parameter names. Are these functions passed anything useful? Anyway for them to get hold of the myResource state or default param string?

Comment: There is also an actions.interceptor options, but it only accepts response interceptors, not request interceptors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a request interceptor for this:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       //config.params contains query/request parameters
       if (config.params){
         //Do something here...
       }
       return config;
    }
  };
});
```